# LinkedIn & Twitter, Share website image through URL

Tags: twitter, linkedin-api, imageurl, socialshare

Following sample URLs helping me to share images to Facebook, GooglePlus and Pinterest:

**GooglePlus**: https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png

**Facebook**: https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png

**Pinterest**: https://in.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=&media=https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png

Like this, I curious to know, is any Twitter and LinkedIn URL formats that allow image sharing(*with just an image URL*)...

Thanks!

Comment: https://twitter.com/share?url=...

Comment: @JeffProd Just tried you given URL format, by which I can share the URL but I want to show the sharing image like as I listed for facebook, googleplus and pinterest

Answer (score 0):

*Twitter...*

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url={url}&text={title}&via={user_id}&hashtags={hash_tags}
```

Source: [Official Twitter Share URL Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview).

*Linkedin...*

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: [Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context)

Want to be able to customize the preview of your page, for `title`, `description`, `image`, etc.?  Then check out the necessary `og:` tags.  Here's LinkedIn documentation for it, but the same documentation applies mostly to all services.

Source: [Open Graph Tags Documentation from LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en).